# adaptable function to slice up nested lists?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

If I have a square matrix as a nested list in python I can split it up into several equal sized boxes and create a new list where each element is a list of the numbers in one of those boxes. E.g.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8],
     [9, 10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15 ,16]]

b = [[a[0][0], a[0][1], a[1][0], a[1][1]],
     [a[0][2], a[0][3], a[1][2], a[1][3]],
     [a[2][0], a[2][1], a[3][0], a[3][1]],
     [a[2][2], a[2][3], a[3][2], a[3][3]]]
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a way to set this up as a function which I can apply to matrices of different sizes and also specify the size of the boxes?

Comment: probably doesn't matter but i forgot to mention that this is for use in python 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is equivalent to what you have and a bit more concise:

```
b = [a[0][:2] + a[1][:2],
     a[0][2:] + a[1][2:],
     a[2][:2] + a[3][:2],
     a[2][2:] + a[3][2:]]
```

Or an equivalent list comprehension:

```
b = [a[i][s] + a[i+1][s] for i in (0,2) for s in (slice(None,2), slice(2,None))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the list comprehension is what I'm looking for, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [31]: import numpy as np

In [32]: a = np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)

In [33]: a
Out[33]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])

In [34]: b = a.reshape(-1,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(4,4)

In [35]: b
Out[35]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```